# Excel pivot table filter when data is missing

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm creating an Excel sheet for complaints, each new complaint goes in a new row. I want to count how many times each complaint was answered compared to its deadline. I have a column which adds on the correct timescale to when the complaint was first received to get the deadline. Another column compares the actual completed date with the deadline and responds **Yes** if it's in time, **No** if its overdue, and **Ongoing** if there is a date received but no completed date filled in.

I created some Pivot Tables to count each Yes, No, and Ongoing compared to each workplace section. I then use a formula to copy the data from the Pivot Table into a 'Performance' tab to make it easier to read.
My problem though is that I'm just setting up this sheet to be used throughout the year so none of the complaints are past their deadline - there aren't any **No** or **Ongoing** responses yet.

I filled in some dummy information so that I could set the Pivot Table filter, but when I delete the dummy data the filter goes too, so instead of counting the number of **No** responses, its just counting all of them. It counts the 3 **Yes** complaints received, which I've already counted in another column in my performance tab.

Basically my question is - is there a way to specify the Pivot Table to filter data by a value that isn't already there in the data? 
Tried Googling this but I can't find the answer... any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using three separate pivot tables - one for Yes,  one for No and one for Ongoing. It would probably be simpler to just use one. I've created some dummy data which I hope approximates your situation. I've converted the range into a Table and named it complaints.

[image]

In the pivot table starting in cell B15, I have "status" on columns and "workplace_section" on rows. In the values I have count of complaint_id.

I have mocked up a possible "performance" table as well. I define which columns and rows I want, then use this formula to retrieve the count from the pivot table. This formula is in cell J15:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("complaint_id",$B$15,"workplace_section",J$14,"status",$I15),0)
```

The GETPIVOTDATA function says "return the aggregate of complaint_id (in this case, 'Count of complaint_id'), for the workplace section found in cell J14 and the status found in cell I15. If either a workplace section or a status is not found in their respective fields in the pivot table, GETPIVOTDATA will return a #REF! error, so I have wrapped it in IFERROR and used the second parameter to return a zero in case those items are not found. So, it can't find Yes or No in the status field, it returns an error, which is converted to a zero.

That's one way of doing it.

A simpler way still is to bypass the pivot table altogether and just use COUNTIFS:

[image]

The formula in cell J27:

```
=COUNTIFS(complaints[status],$I27,complaints[workplace_section],J$26)
```

This is saying, count the rows in the complaints table whose status is the value in column I and whose workplace section is the value in row 26.

I hope this helps. It's difficult to say without some screenshots of your source data and your hoped-for Performance output.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Took me a while to get my head round it but it is exactly what I needed. I did have separate PivotTables which were totally unnecessary, so thanks for that. Kudos for the Simpsons/Monorail complaint too!